# What does the statement below mean?

Tags: groovy

```
assert !destinationDirectory: "Destination directory is required to create an archive"
```

Does this mean that if the destinationDirectory is null the message next to it should be returned with the AssertionError??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can tell by simply running a test.  Run this:

```
assert false
```

You get:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert false


    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:386)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:658)
    at ConsoleScript5.run(ConsoleScript5:1)
        ....
```

However, this:

```
assert false: "This is false!"
```

Gives:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: This is false!. Expression: false
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:388)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:658)
    at ConsoleScript6.run(ConsoleScript6:1)
```

I couldn't find documentation to verify it, but I probably just missed it.  [It also looks like](http://kousenit.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/assert-assertequals-duh/) this format works the same: `assert test, "message"`.